# Kaspersky Total Security Data Vault encryption AES256 BUT with "effective key-length 56bit"

Tags: cryptography, vulnerability, aes, antivirus, sensitive-data-exposure

While comparing Kaspersky Total Security (KST) with Kaspersky Internet Security (KIS). One of the "extras" of KTS is the added "feature" of "Data Vaults", which "encrypts with AES256 with an effective key-length of 56bits". Obviously AES is defined for 256bits but somehow the entropy going into the key is reduced (e.g. 56 random bits fed to some KDF or SHA256 to stretch it).

I would like to know if someone has any information about the supposedly data protection feature f Data Vaults. With 56bits of security, it is well under the current state-of-art feasible limit and easily brute-forceable! Why would Kaspersky implement a feature that is by design weak? I understand that there exist cryptographic export regulations etc., but the KST Data Vaults are weak in ALL versions, not just versions that are to be distributed to restricted regions.

Moreover, even though I have the KIS version, which doesn't have Data Vaults, I found out the Kaspersky Labs Cryptographic Module (56bit) in my Program Files folder. Any thoughts as to why it got installed and if it's used anywhere?

Aside from the above, the fact that a Google search didn't shed much light into the 56bit AES situation strikes me as odd. There have been a few mentions in some websites but nowhere near to the fuss I would expect from the encryption being effectively broken. This also undermines another product, Kaspersky Password Manager (KPM). Does KPM use the same weakened 56bit AES?

Comment: I considered adding it to the Cryptography site, but I am more concerned as to the motives behind this implementation. The related question that's already answered on the Cryptography site is about whether the implementation is secure, which is already known NOT to be...

Comment: 56 bits is the maximum information you'd get out of an 8-character ASCII password so that number appears in some legacy systems. But that security level has never been considered secure within the last 40 years or so. It might be sufficient if the threat model is an attacker who manually tries out passwords. The best possible interpretation would be that they're saying that the encryption is only as secure as the password, and most passwords are pretty bad. The worst possible interpretation is that they're intentionally misleading non-technical people.